# Ubuntu 18 NetworkManager causing boot problem

Tags: boot, 18.04, login, network-manager

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 on a HP Pavillion laptop

```
uname -a
Linux davcra 4.18.0-18-generic #19~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 5 10:22:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On start up I get to the login screen but after that it just hangs at a black screen. If I boot in recovery mode, drop to root and stop NetworkManager it boots fine.

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

A quick google finds many similar sounding problems but nothing that really helped. Anyway as I don't want to have to go through recovery mode every time I want to use my laptop I'd like to know if anyone has a solution. I suppose I could uninstall NetworkManager but it is kinda handy. Any ideas???

Comment: Probably not a NM problem. At the GRUB screen, select the regular boot item, hit the "e" key to edit, find "quiet splash", change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", hit control-x or F10 to continue to boot, login and see if you can. Screen resolution may be off, but that's OK. Report back.

Comment: Seems to have worked and resolution is fine, thanks.

Comment: That means that you've got a problem with your video card or driver. What brand/make/model is your video card, and what video driver/version do you have installed?

Comment: I have a NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1) and the driver=i915

Comment: You have two video cards in your machine. The i915 is for the Intel card. You have a separate driver for the Nvidia. What version is it? Also, if you go to `Software & Updates`, `Additional Drivers` tab, tell me what you see.

Comment: Additional drivers tab shows it shows "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested)" is selected and there is also an option for "Using X.Org X server - Nouveau driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau  (open source)". And lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use' gives 
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: Try the nouveau driver, and then you can try Nvidia 418.56 from their web site. Report back.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the delay getting back but I was away. So the nouveau driver works but the fan seems to run all the time. I installed nvidia-418 which seems to work with no issues (so far).

Comment: Sounds like it's working. Great! Let me put together a quickie answer for you. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

The problem is not with NetworkManager.

It's a video driver problem.

Installed Nvidia 418.56 and the system seems to be working well. At this time, there may even be a newer Nvidia driver for your video card. Check at https://www.nvidia.com.